# Why can't I insert users to my Heroku database in react.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend, heroku-postgres

I've created a new database of users using PosgreSQL and uploaded it to Heroku to try it online.
For some reasons, I can't insert a new user to my database based on Heroku. I've checked the variables inside the table and they all match to the data I send to it.

This is my server.js file code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const knex = require('knex');

const db = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true,
    }
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('this is working')
})


app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
    console.log(email, firstName, lastName)
    if (email && firstName && lastName) {
        db('users')
            .returning('*')
            .insert({
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                joined: new Date()
            })
     /// this is where the error appears. Chrome displays "insert error"
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('insert error'))
            .then(user => { res.json(users[0]); })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('returning error'))
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).json('Error creating new user');
    }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

This is the React code block trigering the insert function to add a user to the database:

```
const SignUpRegularay = () => {
    const [FirstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [LastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [Password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [ConfPassword, setConfPassword] = useState('');

    const SignUp = () => {
        if (Password !== ConfPassword){
            console.log("Passwords don't match");
            return;
        }
        fetch('https:/groupbuyproj.herokuapp.com/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: Email,
                firstName: FirstName,
                lastName: LastName
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(user => {
                if (user) {
                    console.log(user);
                }
            })
    }
    return (
        <StyledContainer>
            <StyledInput onInput={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)} placeholder="First Name" type="text" />
            <StyledInput onInput={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)} placeholder="Last name" type="text" />
            <StyledInput onInput={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Email Address" type="email" />
            <StyledInput onInput={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" type="password" />
            <StyledInput onInput={(e) => setConfPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Rewrite Password" type="password" />
            <StyledButton onClick={SignUp}>SIGN UP</StyledButton>
        </StyledContainer>
    )
}
export default SignUpRegularay;
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to add a new user:
[UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5mb1.jpg)